# Merge tags [difference-in-meaning] and [differences]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

A recent tag (about 1.5 months ago) was added under the name [difference-in-meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference-in-meaning) and is now used by 5 questions, but I believe it is a duplicate of the tag [differences](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differences), used by 3,513 questions.

With so few questions impacted, the easiest course of action could be to have a users with the [edit privilege](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) (2,000 reputation) directly replacing the tag in those 5 questions. Otherwise, an alternative could be to make those tags synonyms.

What do you think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can get rid of [difference-in-meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference-in-meaning) as it is being used inconsistently as a synonym for either [differences](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differences) or [word-choice](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice).

Since there are so few instances I've gone and cleaned them up.